# jQquery: change event fires even when it should not

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, onchange

I am building an application where ID are generated and the after AJAX call is done, the ID is appended to input as it's value. When this happens, the 'change' event is fired by calling .trigger('change') on the input. The code that does this is as follows:

```
$('form.card').each(function(index, element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save-content.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $ajaxData,
        success: function(returnData){ // the ID is received as 'returnData'
            if ($create) { $(element).children('input[name=id]').val(returnData).trigger('change');
            //ID added as input value and 'change' event is triggered
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I use a jQuery File Upload plugin. Every time a file is done uploading, the 'done' event is triggered on each file. Since the ID is received via ajax, the script checks if there is any value, and if not, it attaches an event listener for input 'change'. The code is as follows (including the part from jQuery File Upload plugin):

```
$('form.fileupload').fileupload({
//some plugin setup
    done: function (e, data) {

        //get the input from sibling form (that is the input the 'change' event is triggered on (as described in the previous code))
        $id = $(this).siblings('form.card').children('input[name=id]');

        //if the input has value, do AJAX imediatelly, else wait for id 'change' event to be triggered
        if($id.val()) {
            //do the AJAX magic now
        }                   
        else {
            //when 'change' event is fired, do the AJAX stuff
            $(document).one('change', $id, function() {
                //'change' event fired, do the AJAX magic
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And now the problem: the change event in the second code is received even when it was triggered on other input[name=id] (from another form.card which has its own input[name=id]). Let me explain that: the first code is ran on each form.card, each having its own input[name=id] which the event is triggered on when ID from AJAX is appended. Then, when we upload the file from jQuery File upload plugin (which can be ran on multiple form.fileupload), the done event fires, registers listener for change event. And when you upload the file from let's say third form.fileupload, the event listener from the third form.fileupload done event catches change even from the first form.

And that has been driving me crazy for 2 days now. I have checked the objects that the event is triggered on and listener for: they're the same.

So what I need is the event listener attached to input[name=id] in third form.card to catch only change event from the input[name=id] in third form.card, not the first.

**EDIT:** Here is a fiddle of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/yjnoaye2/3/ Timeouts added to mimic AJAX response delay.

Comment: Sounds to me like event propagation, it would be helpful if you can show a fiddle of this.

Comment: With @saar, you're suffering from propagation ('bubbling').

Comment: I'll try to create a fiddle of this in a minute. However, how can the change event bubble since it is triggered on the specified object?

Comment: I have now eddited the question and added link to a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comment it looks like you have event propagation issue.

you can learn about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation

Comment: I have now added a fiddle so you can see the problem in action.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a namespace to your own event, such that only your listener will hear it.

```
trigger('change.myCustomChangeEvent')
...
$(document).one('change.myCustomChangeEvent', $id, function() {
```

See the section on namespaces here:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I have tried to add my custom event name to the fiddle and that works... however in my real code, that does not work...

Comment: well that does not work either, the previous comment is not true

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have it now. The problem was, that the event listener was created on document and not the form.card that the input[name=id] is in. Even I have scpecified the exact object in the selector parameter, the event listener was attached to every input[name=id].

So all I needed to do was to change this:

```
$(document).one('change', $id, function() {
    //'change' event fired, do the AJAX magic
});
```

to this

```
$(this).siblings('form.card').one('change', $id, function() {
    //'change' event fired, do the AJAX magic
});
```

This way, the event listener is attached to particular input in particular form.card.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yjnoaye2/5/